# For which a is this function injective?

Tags: functions

In my mathematics prep course I found this question: For which $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is the function $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}, f(x)=ax^2+x+1$ injective?

I've calculated that if $a\geq0$ then $f$ is strictly monotonically increasing on $\mathbb{N}$, therefore injective. And if $a <0$, then $f$ has a local maxima at $x=-\frac{1}{2a}$ , which means for all $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $f(-\frac{1}{2a}+\varepsilon)=f(-\frac{1}{2a}-\varepsilon)$. Now I need to somehow characterise $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\left(\frac{1}{2a}\pm\varepsilon\right)$ are not natural numbers. How to do that?

Also, the question says that $f$ is a mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. However very obviously $f$ can map to many non-natural numbers. Is this an error in the question? Or would this question be considered a trick question?

Comment: That $a\in \mathbb R$ vs. $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ seems indeed strange. For a prep course, I would **assume** no trickery, so make sure to recheck the source again (maybe it says $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f(m)=f(n)$ for two distinct naturals $m$ and $n$. Then
$$am^2+m+1=an^2+n+1\\
\implies a(m-n)(m+n)+m-n=0\\
\implies a=-\dfrac1{m+n}$$
Therefore, $a$ should not be of the form $-\dfrac 1k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N\setminus \{1\}$ for $f$ to be injective.